# namespace missing in VS 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I have installed VB.NET express 2010 version and I am trying to create a new dll file for use in my SSIS packages. When I try to write the code, the VS environment tells me that I dont have the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime Namespace. What can I do to make this possible?

I looked around on internet but couldn't find anything substantial. I also have BIDS 2008 which I use to create packages. I cannot uninstall that because I have some work to do on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Add Reference dialog window, click on the browse tab.  Then navigate your way to:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies
```

There you will find the `Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll`, select it and hit okay...

Comment: I dont see the SDK folder in there. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Found it. It was in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a project reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll`.